# Power BI + Snowflake SSO

Tags: powerbi, single-sign-on, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

## Snowflake

## PowerBI

Is it possible to use different warehouse in snowflake for data refresh in Power BI than warehouse used for dashboard development?

I'd like to have separate warehouse for data refresh in order to be able to track snowflake expenses.

Let's say I'm using SF_TUTS_WH as a warehouse for development, but I'd like to use PBI_WH as warehouse for data refresh in PowerBI. Is it possible to achieve this or do I have to change snowflake warehouse in PowerBI file before I'll load it to PBI online?

[image]

FYI: `https://www.snowflake.com/blog/using-sso-between-power-bi-and-snowflake/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option  which will work for you is to have the ware house name paramterized for the reports. The value  of the parameter can be updated from the service based on the requirements.Please check out the below video link to see how the parameters can be updated in the power bi service.

https://youtu.be/MJVSu47iMmo

Hope this helps

---

Thanks ,
Prasanth